# Why am I getting an end of file exception when trying to use serialization on a hash map in java?

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

```
    public static void updateNumberOfEpsWatched() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Progress/HashMapStorage.ser"));
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Progress/HashMapStorage.ser"));
        HashMap<String,Integer> mapToWrite = new HashMap<>();
        mapToWrite.put("one", 1);
        out.writeObject(mapToWrite);
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Integer>) in.readObject();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        System.out.println(hashMap);
    }
```

The program is able to write a hashmap to a file and then read it back properly but if I comment out the `"out.writeObject(mapToWrite);"` then it can't read back the hashmap even though the file is still there. I am trying to make it so that the hashmap can be stored by the program before the program ends and then read back when the user launched the program so that it's data persists multiple uses of the program.

I was expecting to be able to comment out the `"out.writeObject(mapToWrite);"` and then it would be able to read the file written to before. I have tried closing the object writer but it made no difference. There error code was:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at Ch01_11_2024_progress.main(Ch01_11_2024_progress.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1711)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:538)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:496)
    at Ch01_11_2024_progress.updateNumberOfEpsWatched(Ch01_11_2024_progress.java:27)
    at Ch01_11_2024_progress.main(Ch01_11_2024_progress.java:10)
```

Comment: Actually, quite frankly, why not simply wrap an if else based on condition whether it writes the file or creates the file. (nb next time round the file creator each iteration of use is making a new file it seems , if you jumped the file write obj then there is an empty file been created !!! e.g. the one that was there has been deleted)

Comment: ohhhh, I assumed that if an object writer was initialized but not used then it didn't change the file. This explains why that was happening.

Comment: If your file were to have ONLY the content from each individual write , then it would need to be truncated to zero length or deleted  , if it kept it but more were placed in it, it would need to set up as an "append". So instantiating an object pointed to the file to write to would delete or truncate ,BUT , if it increments or patterns the filename to be unique each write , the file may be there but not known to be the file to read is another possibility.

Comment: The problem is that you have overwritten the input file with the output file. This makes no sense. Close the output file and then open the input file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is related to how you are handling the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. When you create the ObjectOutputStream, it writes a header to the file, and when you close it, it writes a trailer. If you don't write any objects in between, the file might end up being empty or contain only the header and trailer.

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```java
public static void updateNumberOfEpsWatched() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    // Writing to the file
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Progress/HashMapStorage.ser"));
    HashMap<String, Integer> mapToWrite = new HashMap<>();
    mapToWrite.put("one", 1);
    out.writeObject(mapToWrite);
    out.close();

    // Reading from the file
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Progress/HashMapStorage.ser"));
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = (HashMap<String, Integer>) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    
    System.out.println(hashMap);
}
```

In this corrected version, I removed the unnecessary read operation after the ObjectOutputStream was closed and added a separate read section after closing the ObjectInputStream. This way, you ensure that the file is properly closed after writing before attempting to read from it. The original issue occurred because the file might not have been completely written when you tried to read it without closing the ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: is there any documentation or reference for "when you close it, it writes a trailer" ?

Comment: ( Also strongly recommended to use try-with-resource instead of `close()` )

Comment: The issue has nothing to with serialization at all. Same would happen with other streams. Just a bizarre order of opening and closing files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).